# How to prevent certain bundled CKEditor plugins from loading

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

There is `hook_ckeditor_settings_alter()` to change/alter CKEditor settings. But I can't find a way to prevent certain CKEditor plugins from loading.

I am trying to achieve similar behaviors as here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2546048#comment-10188390 but that is for wysiwyg module, we don't use wysiwyg module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can disable CKEditor plugins by following hook as show with the example for disabling image and image2 plugins:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ckeditor_settings_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_ckeditor_settings_alter(&$settings, $conf) {
  // Comma separate names of plugins to remove.
  $plugins_to_remove = 'image,image2';
  $settings['removePlugins'] = !empty($settings['removePlugins'])
    ? $settings['removePlugins'] . ',' . $plugins_to_remove
    : $plugins_to_remove;
}
```

(taken from my own article: http://kb.detlus.com/articles/drupal/drupal-7-disable-ckeditor-bundled-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

CKeditor plugins are enabled/disabled directly from Ckeditor profils.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant about bundled plugins that comes with CKEditor library itself.